# How to get an Arrow's Array's TimeUnit C++

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

It's a very simple example. I am trying to extract the TimeUnit::type from the DataType.

```
array = arrow::Array *array

auto a = static_cast<arrow::Date64Array*>(array);            
arrow::TimeUnit::type unit =  a->type()->unit();
```

I didn't find any specific in the Docs but the `type.h` says that there should be a public .Unit or .unit() but I can't find any of them. Did I miss something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `arrow::DateUnit unit = a->type()->unit();` or easier: `auto unit = a->type()->unit();`? Otherwise please provide the error message.

Comment: arrow::DateUnit doesn't seem to be a thing in C++ api. 
But the problem is even before the type definition, When copiling `a->type()->unit()` gives the following error: `error: class "arrow::DataType" has no member "unit"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My C++ is a little bit slow, and partially looks like `arrow::DateUnit` is not exported in the C++ api for whatever reason.

```
array = arrow::Array *array
auto &ty = static_cast<arrow::Time64Type&>(*array->type());
arrow::DateUnit unit = ty.unit();
```

As a bonus I was trying to do this for timestamp (and other times) as well, which is slightly different since they return `arrow::TimeUnit::type` instead:

```
array = arrow::Array *array
auto &ty = static_cast<arrow::TimestampType&>(*array->type());
arrow::TimeUnit::type unit = ty.unit();
```